# How to use nextPageToken from youtube data api v3 to load more videos in android recycler view

Tags: android, json, parsing, youtube-data-api

I'm building an application where I have an Recycler View which has my YouTube channel videos. Everything works fine. I get my first 10 results successfully .but now when user scrolls down and reaches 10th result I want to load next 10 results,

my json response has nextPageToken but i dont know how to use nextPageToken to load next page videos in my recycler view, 
Any help ?

```
  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=10&playlistId=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_XOgcRukSoKKjewFJZrKV0&fields=nextPageToken,items(id,snippet(title,description,position,thumbnails(medium,high),resourceId/videoId))&key=API_KEY;
```

json parsing code :

```
    private ArrayList<VideoData> parseJSONReaponse(JSONObject response) {
    ArrayList<VideoData> listVideos = new ArrayList<>();
    if (response != null || response.length() > 0) {

        String nextPageToken = Constants.NA;
        try {

            if (response.has(KEY_NEXTPAGETOKEN)
                    && !response.isNull(KEY_NEXTPAGETOKEN) ){
                nextPageToken = response.getString(KEY_NEXTPAGETOKEN);
            }

            JSONArray arrayItems = response.getJSONArray(KEY_ITEMS);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayItems.length(); i++) {
                String title = Constants.NA;
                String urlThumbnail = Constants.NA;
                String resourceID = Constants.NA;

                JSONObject currentItems = arrayItems.getJSONObject(i);

                if (currentItems.has(KEY_SNIPPET)
                        && !currentItems.isNull(KEY_SNIPPET)) {
                    JSONObject objectSnippet = currentItems.getJSONObject(KEY_SNIPPET);

                    if (objectSnippet.has(KEY_TITLE)
                            && !objectSnippet.isNull(KEY_TITLE)) {
                        title = objectSnippet.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                    }

                    if (objectSnippet.has(KEY_THUMBNAIL)
                            && !objectSnippet.isNull(KEY_THUMBNAIL)) {
                        JSONObject objectThumbnail = objectSnippet.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMBNAIL);


                        if (objectThumbnail.has(KEY_THUMBNAIL_MEDIUM)
                                && !objectThumbnail.isNull(KEY_THUMBNAIL_MEDIUM)) {
                            JSONObject objectThumbnailMedium = objectThumbnail.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMBNAIL_MEDIUM);


                            if (objectThumbnailMedium.has(KEY_THUMBNAIL_MEDIUM_URL)
                                    && !objectThumbnailMedium.isNull(KEY_THUMBNAIL_MEDIUM_URL)) {
                                urlThumbnail = objectThumbnailMedium.getString(KEY_THUMBNAIL_MEDIUM_URL);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (objectSnippet.has(KEY_RESOURCEID)
                            && !objectSnippet.isNull(KEY_RESOURCEID)) {
                        JSONObject objectResourceId = objectSnippet.getJSONObject(KEY_RESOURCEID);

                        if (objectResourceId.has(KEY_VIDEOID)
                                && !objectResourceId.isNull(KEY_VIDEOID)) {
                            resourceID = objectResourceId.getString(KEY_VIDEOID);
                        }
                    }
                }

                VideoData videoData = new VideoData();
                videoData.setTitle(title);
                videoData.setUrlThumbnail(urlThumbnail);
                videoData.setVideoId(resourceID);

                if (!title.equals(Constants.NA)){
                    listVideos.add(videoData);
                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return listVideos;
}
```

Comment: You have found any answer of this ? please share me if you found ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try making the same request but with an extra param `pageToken=<the-nextPageToken-you-received>`

Answer (score 0):

In your Url Just change the  `maxResults=your value` and it will load your videos

Thanks

Comment: No!. There is a Limit for maxResult(i.e from 0-50)